# mstsc process takes more than 2 GB of RAM on a the remote machine

Tags: memory, remote-desktop, windows-server-2003

From time to time on a remote server (64-bit) I find that it's RAM (4GB) being filled up. When I check the processes list in the task manager I find the mstsc taking very low amount of RAM but If I check it using process explorer I can see it's taking more than 2GBs of RAM.

Why would it take up to 2 GBs of RAM on the remote machine ?

Comment: This service is incharge of the terminal connections.  If its taking that much memory it would be based on how much data is being transfered between the connection itself.  Since when was there a different between Task Manager and Process Explorer?

Comment: @Ramhound, mstsc "Private Bytes" was 2+ GBs (Virtual Memory), while "Task Manager" only shows the "Private Working Set" (I guess this is the amount of memory in the RAM taken), sorry I wasn't clear about that point. What do you mean by "The connection itself" ? When I killed that process I didn't notice anything going wrong ! Is there a way to control how much memory it would take ?